# Special significance of share named "apps$" on Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, samba, network-share

The customer's IT department setup a share on their server called

```
\\servername\apps$
```

where then our software resides

```
\\servername\apps$\UniversalExports\HyperionPro.exe
```

Normally this share is invisible; presumably because of the "$" on the end.

Is there some special meaning for a share named **apps$**? Is there something with replication or automatic discovery on Windows Server 2003?

**Note:** Googling for `apps$` will not work because google (and StackOverflow) ignore the **$** on the end. Any results you do get will be related to iPhone apps.

Comment: Why not ask them?  Any admin can make hidden shares.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No particular significance, the $ as you said makes it a hidden share, and I guess they just chose "apps" for the name cos it made sense, being descriptive of it's contents.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a share they have setup to roll out apps through group policy?

Comment: +1 for this;  not all hidden shares are "official" and they could have added one for this purpose.  Another use:  Redirected folders

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that's not the normal name of a hidden share.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share#Share_names

I don't think that removing it will harm the computer, but it may stop other applications from working if they depend on it.  You should find out who is connecting to it via Windows Management, and Shared Folders.  This will tell you who is connecting to it, but it is not a vital windows share (in fact, none of the hidden admin shares are).

Edit: Another link that lists hidden shares: http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/hiddshar.htm

Comment: Quibble:  IPC$ would probably ruin your day if you deleted it from a server.

Comment: I don't think you're even capable of deleting that one though... it's more of a named pipe than a hidden share isn't it?